# Objective-c get object that was called selector

Tags: objective-c, selector

Is it possible to get id pointer to object which was called selector inside function with no sender argument?

```
- (void)didSomeThing {//delegate method may call from any object
//how to get sender = someObj?
id sender = ??
} 
....
//calling
[someObj didSomeThing];
...
```

Comment: may be its in global you can get

Comment: Why does the method need to know the caller?  (It's usually a bad way to design things.)

Comment: i know it is bad, but i have a lib with bugs and i have just headers and many delegate selectors. How to get selector called class name?

Comment: it's great, but back trace not working with hidden selectors inside C libs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't find out who is sender.

Every time you send message to object compiler transform it to:

```
objc_msgSend(receiver, selector, arg1, arg2, ...)
```

As you can see here is no way you can find out who is calling method except passing sender as parameter.

You can read more about it here in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH104-SW1)